# How to set default value for taxonomy autocomplete field?

Tags: 7, forms

I am using Drupal 7. I have created a content type with autocomplete taxonomy field. I need to set default value programmatically.
I am using this code under `hook_form_alter`:

```
$form['field_school_locality_city_level'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['names']['#default_value'] = tid;
```

It's giving me just `term id`, but I need it in format `Bhopal[tid:8193]`.

Answer (score 3):

Load taxonomy term using term id then, generate data in your required format.

```
 // Term id.
 $tid = 8193;   
 // Obtain the term. 
 $term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
 // Format data.
 $data = $term->name . '[tid:' . $tid .']';

$form['field_school_locality_city_level'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['names']['#default_value'] = $data;
```

Comment: I have used this. its giving me above result.